# How do I pass class names as arguments?

Tags: vba

I want to make a function that accepts a class exemplar/class name and returns a collection of a certain number of exemplars of said class, initalized and populated. So far I have come up with this solution:

```
Function getCollectionObj(className as string) As Collection

    Dim obj As Variant
    Dim result As Collection
    Dim objType As String
    Dim I 
    
    For I = 1 To 5
    
    'selecting the type of a class based on string name
    Select Case className
    Case "Cls1"
        Set obj = New Cls1
    Case "Cls2"
        Set obj = New Cls2
    Case "DocumentStart"
        Set obj = New Cls3    
    End Select
    'some code handling the exemplar of the object.

    result.add obj
    Next I
    Set getCollectionObj = result
End Function
```

The problem with this is I have to explicitly put every class into `select case` and that the code has to select and declare the cerain class every time, even though all object in the collection should be the exemplars of the same class. How do I improve it?

**Edit: my testing code (gives "object required error")**

Main module:

```
Private Function getCollectionObj(ByVal factory As IObjectFactory) As Collection
Dim I
    For I = 1 To 5
    result.Add factory.Create
    Next I
End Function

Sub test()
Dim var As Object
Set var = getCollectionObj(New Class1ObjectFactory)
End Sub
```

IObjectFactory class:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function Create() As Object

End Function
```

Cls1Factory class (the right dropdown shows "create" when the function is selected):

```
Option Explicit
Implements IObjectFactory

Private Function IObjectFactory_Create() As Object
     ' "Object required" error here
     Set IObjectFactory_Create = New Cls1
End Function
```

Cls1 class:

```
Option Explicit
Public I As String
```

Comment: With a title like "function to create a collection of objects of a particular type" I think this would make a fine post on [codereview.se]. From an object-oriented perspective, the problem you are trying to solve can be solved by passing in an *abstract factory* instead of a class name; the factory interface needs an implementation (a separate class with an `Implements TheAbstractFactoryInterface` statement) for each class that can be created, and the caller decides what type gets into the collection by deciding what factory implementation to inject into the method/function.

Comment: Seems like the lowest-maintenance approach would be to create a function "ObjectfromClassName" and use that to implement the `Select Case` and return an object of the correct type - then you only have one "thing" to maintain if you add a class (other than the code where you consume that type...)

Comment: FYI I've edited my post to include a more thorough response to your edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ideally, you don't (to answer the question as titled) - that way your code doesn't silently break when a class gets renamed, for example.

There's a better way, one that gives you an immediate compile-time error as soon as something breaks, and that works nicely with static code analysis and refactoring tools, such as [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) - full disclosure, that's my website, and I manage the Rubberduck open-source project.

You could formalize the task of *creating an instance of a class* by defining an *abstract factory* interface. Add a new class module, call it `IObjectFactory`:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function Create() As Object
End Function
```

Now add a new class module, call it `Cls1Factory` and make it implement the abstract factory interface:

```
Option Explicit
Implements IObjectFactory

Private Function IObjectFactory_Create() As Object
    Set IObjectFactory_Create = New Cls1
End Function
```

Add a new class module, call it `Cls2Factory` and make it also implement the abstract factory interface:

```
Option Explicit
Implements IObjectFactory

Private Function IObjectFactory_Create() As Object
    Set IObjectFactory_Create = New Cls2
End Function
```

Add another implementation that can create `Cls3` instances, call it `Cls3Factory`.

Then change your function's signature as follows:

```
Public Function getCollectionObj(ByVal factory As IObjectFactory) As Collection
```

Now the entire `Select Case` block becomes this single statement:

```
result.Add factory.Create
```

The calling code that used to do this:

```
Set things1 = getCollectionObj("Cls1")
Set things2 = getCollectionObj("Cls2")
Set things3 = getCollectionObj("Cls3")
```

Now needs to do this:

```
Set things1 = getCollectionObj(New Cls1Factory)
Set things2 = getCollectionObj(New Cls2Factory)
Set things3 = getCollectionObj(New Cls3Factory)
```

The function can now create a collection of 5 instances of any class you want, without modifying it at all: if you need to support a new class, simply implement a new factory for it, and then pass it as a parameter to the function.

---

RE: EDIT

Rubberduck's static code analysis can help you avoid a ton of traps, exactly like those in your edited snippet: the function return value isn't assigned, result variable is accessed before it's initialized, etc.:

[image: OP's revision 2 code under ducky scrutiny]

The "object required" error is signaled by its underlying causes, here in cascading order leading to this specific error:

- *'Option Explicit' is not specified in 'Module1'.*
- *Local variable 'result' is not declared.*
- *Variable 'result' is used but not assigned.*

`Option Explicit` not being specified has allowed the code to execute with `result` not being declared. Since it's not declared, it's allocated as a `Variant/Empty` until it's assigned... except it never is, and when a member call (`.Add`) is tentatively being made against that variant, that's when VBA screams *at run-time* and says "object required", because *an object is required* for that member call to be valid. But all VBA is seeing is a `Variant/Empty` pointer it just created on-the-spot.

The run-time error is raised *after* the `.Create` factory method call returns, but *before* the returned object is passed as a parameter to an *accidentally late-bound* `.Add` member call. Execution hasn't entered the `.Add` method, VBA hasn't successfully dereferenced a `Collection` object from the `result` variable; but because the debugger doesn't let us step through operators, when we click "DEBUG" we're taken back on the failing statement, and the entire `result.Add factory.Create` statement is highlighted (as opposed to just the `result.Add` call that's the actually-failing operation here).

*Because* there are two statements on the same line, the debugger is not quite in the exact state it should be in right now. If we hit F8, we're taken back into the factory method, and if we don't realize what's going on then it's easy to let the debugger lead us astray into investigating a completely sane execution path.

Separate the statements:

```
Dim o As Object
Set o = factory.Create '<~ no problem here!

result.Add o '<~ object required
```

Now the debugger enters break mode with the correct failing statement highlighted.

The working code, for completeness' sake:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim var As Collection
    Set var = getCollectionObj(New Class1ObjectFactory)
    Debug.Print var.Count
End Sub

Private Function getCollectionObj(ByVal factory As IObjectFactory) As Collection
    Dim result As Collection
    Set result = New Collection
    Dim I As Long
    For I = 1 To 5
        result.Add factory.Create
    Next I
    Set getCollectionObj = result
End Function
```

Comment: I was reading about interfaces, but I couldn't 100% grasp what are they  for. I guess this is the great opportunity to learn, thank you.

Comment: I tried to run the code, but I get "object required" error within implemented class factory code, after the line ` Set IObjectFactory_Create = New Cls1`

Comment: @IgorCheglakov don't type the interface implementations by hand (same with events), select the interface (or event source) from the left-side dropdown at the top of the code pane; then select the members from the right-side dropdown; the VBE will automatically generate the correct member names. Note that interface member names cannot contain underscores. If the left-side dropdown says `(general)` when the caret is inside the member, then the member is not implementing the interface member (or handling any events).

Comment: Basically "object required" here means 1) `Option Explicit` was left out, and 2) your interface name isn't `IObjectFactory` ;-)

Comment: both errors you have mentioned don't seem to be the case. I have updated my question with my test code. Could you please review it?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, if you already have a license or are willing to buy a license for vbWatchDog Error Handler, one of the perk is the ability to create objects from strings:

```
Set myClass1 = ErrEx.LiveCallstack.ProjectCreateClassInstance("Class1")
```

[Introduced in version 3.8.6](https://www.everythingaccess.com/vbwatchdog/version-history.htm)

Comment: Eh that's kind of cheating ;-) ..will break on refactor/rename though!